# OpenCV convolution on ROI

Tags: c++, opencv, convolution

I am trying to make a convolution on a region of my image, in just one pixel, to be more exact. I also want that this convolution uses the values outside the ROI, when computing the borders of this ROI. To test this, i wrote the following code.

```
float kernelData[25] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

float imgData[9*9] = {0,  0,  0,   0,   0,    0,  0,   0,  0,
                      0,  0,  0,   0,   0,    0,  0,   0,  0,
                      0,  0,  0,   0,   0,    0,  0,   0,  0,
                      0,  0,  0,   2, 256,  128,  0,   0,  0,
                      0,  0,  0,   4,   1,   64,  0,   0,  0,
                      0,  0,  0,   8,  16,   32,  0,   0,  0,
                      0,  0,  0,   0,   0,    0,  0,   0,  0,
                      0,  0,  0,   0,   0,    0,  0,   0,  0,
                      0,  0,  0,   0,   0,    0,  0,   0,  0};

Mat img = Mat(9, 9, CV_32FC1, (void*)imgData);
Mat kernel = Mat(5, 5, CV_32FC1, (void*)kernelData);
Mat window = Mat(img, Rect2i(Point2i(4, 4), Size(1, 1)));

Mat convolved1 = Mat(1, 1, CV_32FC1);
Mat convolved2 = Mat(1, 1, CV_32FC1);
Mat convolved3 = Mat(1, 1, CV_32FC1);
Mat convolved4 = Mat(1, 1, CV_32FC1);
Mat convolved5 = Mat(1, 1, CV_32FC1);

cv::filter2D(window, convolved1, CV_32F, kernel, Point(-1, -1), 0, BORDER_CONSTANT);
cv::filter2D(window, convolved2, CV_32F, kernel, Point(-1, -1), 0, BORDER_REPLICATE);
cv::filter2D(window, convolved3, CV_32F, kernel, Point(-1, -1), 0, BORDER_REFLECT);
cv::filter2D(window, convolved4, CV_32F, kernel, Point(-1, -1), 0, BORDER_REFLECT_101);
cv::filter2D(window, convolved5, CV_32F, kernel, Point(-1, -1), 0, BORDER_TRANSPARENT);

cout << img << endl;
cout << kernel << endl;
cout << window << endl;
cout << convolved1 << endl;
cout << convolved2 << endl;
cout << convolved3 << endl;
cout << convolved4 << endl;
cout << convolved5 << endl;
```

The execution of this code showed this results:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 2, 256, 128, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 64, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 8, 16, 32, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;    
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;    
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 1, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1]
[5]
[5]
[5]
[5]
[5]
```

I have tested all border types, and none of them get right result, 257.
I also tried to modify the kernel, changing the positions of 1's and 0's, and the results i have got are always wrong.

The funny part is that this same code runs correctly on my notebook, but in my desktop it does not.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You could always implement the correlation yourself. I don't think the different border types will change anything; I tried to use `copyMakeBorder()` here with your window and regardless of the border type, it just simply gave me a larger window into the original `image` matrix of which `window` is an ROI. It shows in the documentation for `borderInterpolate` that it's called for filtering functions and for `copyMakeBorder()` so presumably `filter2D` does the same (which is maybe why it works on one machine). Do you have different versions of OpenCV installed on each machine?

Comment: Either way this doesn't seem like behavior you want to rely on if it can change between versions and implementing the correlation filter might be better if you did it yourself.

Comment: What version of OpenCV do you see this on? On 3.0.0 I get 257 for all of the different borders except `BORDER_CONSTANT` (which honestly I didn't expect... it seems very strange behavior to me). As @AlexanderReynolds suggested, it would be easy to write your own by just increasing the window to the same size as the kernel, multiplying and taking the sum, `sum(window.mul(kernel))`.

Comment: @beaker I'm getting his same values (`[5]` for everything) on `3.2.0`.

Comment: Sorry for taking to long to answer. @AlexanderReynolds, i am using different versions on each machine. 3.2 on my desktop, and 3.1 on my notebook. I will install opencv 3.3 on both machines, and try your suggestions. Thank you guys. I will come back with results later.

Comment: Increase the window to the kernel size is not working. When i want to compute the convolution on the pixel (0, 0) for example, 'copyMakeBorder' throws an exception saying "_Unknown/unsupported border type in function borderInterpolate_". I tried with all border types.